# Trying to load records from CSV to mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, python-3.x

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','tekno','poop','media')

cursor = conn.cursor()

txt = csv.reader(file('movies.csv'))
for row in txt:
    cursor.execute('insert into shows_and_tv(watched_on,title,score_rating)' 'values     ("%s","%s","%s")',row)

conn.close()
```

when I run this I get

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

but it matches up

the csv is formatted like

```
dd-mm-yyyy,string,tinyint
```

which watches the fields in the database

Comment: I don't know python, but you've got 3 variable placeholders ("%s", "%s", "%s") but only one variable (row)? I'm not sure, but that's all I can see that seems illogical

Comment: Add `print row` to see what you get.

Comment: @Rook `row` can be `tuple` (something like this: `(date,title,int)`) and it can be used this way.

Comment: Do you still need an answer? I can help you adjust the below answer more if desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have a mysql database to play with. So I did what you need but in sqlite. It should be quite easy to adapt this to your needs.

```
import csv
import sqlite3
from collections import namedtuple

conn = sqlite3.connect('statictest.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE if not exists movies (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 'watched_on','title','score_rating')''')

record = namedtuple('record',['watched_on','title','score_rating'])


SQL ='''
INSERT INTO movies ("watched_on","title","score_rating") VALUES (?,?,?)
'''


with open('statictest.csv', 'r') as file:

    read_data = csv.reader(file)
    for row in read_data:
        watched_on, title, score_rating = row
        data = (record(watched_on, title, score_rating))
        c.execute(SQL, data)
        conn.commit()
```